# Is that possible that we use bagging on the combination of a decision tree and a linear separator?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, computer-science, data-mining

Is that possible that we use bagging on the combination of a decision tree and a linear separator?

I know bagging could be used for the decision tree or linear separator individually. but how about the combination?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather complicated question.

Although bagging can be used with decision trees, the original approach doesn't work very well -- the subsampled populations produce highly correlated trees.  The solution generally takes you in the direction of random forests, which are a variation on bagging.

Bagging itself is a form of model voting.  Yes, you can have different models vote for the final result.  You can even have a heterogeneous set of models developed independently to do the voting.  Whether this produces an improved model, I don't know.  Bootstrap aggregation (the formal name of bagging) is usually applied to one type of model -- although in a modified form for decision trees.

Comment: Personally, I think, the use of the linear separator will ruin the performance of bagging. But actually, all we want is to trade off the variance and bias, but the combination could not accomplish it... is that correct?

Comment: @TianyiNi . . . My point is that bagging *per se* is not useful with decision trees.  You should be looking at random forest algorithms.  The randomization on the fields used for splitting is what makes bagging work in that context.